# Lubuntu touchpad click fails occasionally yet logout works

Tags: lubuntu, touchpad, synaptics, lxqt

Synaptics Touchpad occasionally breaks on Lubuntu. The cursor always works, but the tapping doesn't. Logout or reboot will temporaly come to normal. I tried many methods, could not solve the problem. Please help.

$ neofecth

```
OS: Ubuntu 19.10 x86_ 
Host: 4291RF4 ThinkPa 
Kernel: 5.3.0-26-gene 
Uptime: 4 mins 
Packages: 3762 (dpkg) 
Shell: bash 5.0.3 
Resolution: 1366x768 
DE: LXQt 
WM: Openbox 
Theme: Adwaita-dark [ 
Icons: oxygen [GTK2/3 
Terminal: terminator 
CPU: Intel i3-2310M ( 
GPU: Intel 2nd Genera 
Memory: 480MiB / 7844
```

$ xinput list

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint                     id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard         (2)]
↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard     (3)]
↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard     (3)]
↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard     (3)]
↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard     (3)]
↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=10   [slave  keyboard     (3)]
↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=13   [slave  keyboard     (3)]
↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=9    [slave  keyboard     (3)]
```

$ xinput list-props 11

```
Device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad':
Device Enabled (165):   1
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (167): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
Device Accel Profile (298): 1
Device Accel Constant Deceleration (299):   2.500000
Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (300):   1.000000
Device Accel Velocity Scaling (301):    12.500000
Synaptics Edges (302):  1617, 5326, 1597, 4584
Synaptics Finger (303): 25, 30, 0
Synaptics Tap Time (304):   180
Synaptics Tap Move (305):   243
Synaptics Tap Durations (306):  180, 180, 100
Synaptics ClickPad (307):   1
Synaptics Middle Button Timeout (308):  0
Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure (309):    282
Synaptics Two-Finger Width (310):   7
Synaptics Scrolling Distance (311): 110, 110
Synaptics Edge Scrolling (312): 1, 0, 0
Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (313):   1, 0
Synaptics Move Speed (314): 1.000000, 1.750000, 0.036140, 0.000000
Synaptics Off (315):    0
Synaptics Locked Drags (316):   0
Synaptics Locked Drags Timeout (317):   5000
Synaptics Tap Action (318): 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0
Synaptics Click Action (319):   1, 3, 0
Synaptics Circular Scrolling (320): 0
Synaptics Circular Scrolling Distance (321):    0.100000
Synaptics Circular Scrolling Trigger (322): 0
Synaptics Circular Pad (323):   0
Synaptics Palm Detection (324): 0
Synaptics Palm Dimensions (325):    10, 200
Synaptics Coasting Speed (326): 20.000000, 50.000000
Synaptics Pressure Motion (327):    30, 160
Synaptics Pressure Motion Factor (328): 1.000000, 1.000000
Synaptics Resolution Detect (329):  1
Synaptics Grab Event Device (330):  0
Synaptics Gestures (331):   1
Synaptics Capabilities (332):   1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1
Synaptics Pad Resolution (333): 81, 58
Synaptics Area (334):   0, 0, 0, 0
Synaptics Soft Button Areas (335):  3471, 0, 4201, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
Synaptics Noise Cancellation (336): 27, 27
Device Product ID (294):    2, 7
Device Node (293):  "/dev/input/event5"
```

$ cat /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "libinput pointer catchall"
    MatchIsPointer "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Driver "libinput"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "libinput keyboard catchall"
    MatchIsKeyboard "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Driver "libinput"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Driver "libinput"
Option "Tapping" "on"   
EndSection
```

Comment: You haven't provided many details; you've tagged LXQt so I'm guessing it's 18.10 or later - but we cannot know, nor what kernel & age of software stack you are using.

Comment: @guiverc I add the system details, please see if complete information or not